# cant check a checkbox a second time in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to manupilate the input checkbox however everytime i click on the label the first time the checkbox will be selected after that i click the label again and the checkbox is unchecked so far so good. But when i click the label again the checkbox will not be checked.

My jQuery code is as followed

```
$('.form-checkbox label').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {

            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).find('span').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).find('input').attr('CHECKED', false);
        } else {

            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $(this).find('span').addClass('checked');
            $(this).find('input').attr('CHECKED', true);
        }
    });
```

And my HTML is as followed

```
<div class="form-checkbox">
   <label id="checkbox-checkbox">
      <input id="checkbox-checkbox" name="checkbox" value="option1" type="checkbox" /><span></span> Option 1
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note, you should definitely not have 2 ids that are the same

Comment: Thanks i missed that one the label id should be a for attribute

Answer (score 3):

Use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
 $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true/false);
```

See [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should try this

$('.form-checkbox label').on('click', function() {
   var chk = $("#checkbox-checkbox").prop("checked");
   $("#checkbox-checkbox").prop("checked", !chk);
});
```